# Can you identify this small round piece with 2 studs on opposite sides

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Can anyone identify this part? I remember reading that it was part of a wheel, like a hub or something and it's got studs on both sides.
I've searched google for LEGO wheel hubs, and looked through the Bricklink wheels section but haven't found it.

[image: round 1x1 with studs on both sides]

[image: round 1x1 with studs on both sides]

Comment: It is definitely non-LEGO piece. Otherwise it would have made a lot of (positive) noise in LEGO community.

Comment: @Joost I was searching for that question but it had 4081b in the **link URL** only, so the search didn't find it. I've edited it now to (hopefully) make it more findable.